# Teradata queries to python

Tags: python, database, migration, teradata

I like to get each teradata query used in my teradata database into my python program. Is there any way of doing that?
By running the code we should be able to get teradata DDL and DML commands used as output

Comment: I dont fully understand what you want. There's the QryLog which stores info about executed SQL, `dbc.QryLogSQLV` stores the actual SQL code...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.